# Pros and Cons of Fitting a Spatial Regression to Cumulative Data

Tags: regression, spatial

When using regression to estimate a relation between a variable of interest and distance from a certain point (eg a distance-decay curve), what are the advantages and disadvantages of fitting the regression line to cumulative data rather than data by band, and what is the balance of advantage?

The following is a slightly contrived example designed to illustrate the question while avoiding extraneous issues.  Suppose a researcher tags in some way a random sample of 100 nuts growing on a nut tree.  Later, when the nuts have fallen, the researcher identifies where they are, measures their distances from the tree, and counts the numbers by 5 metre distance bands, obtaining the following (hypothetical) data:

[image]

The researcher wants to use the sample to estimate the distance-number relation for the whole population of nuts on the tree.  One approach would be to estimate a regression of N on MD.  Another would be to estimate a regression of CN on D.  The results of either approach can easily be converted to the other form by summing or taking differences.  Is there any advantage in terms of accuracy in the latter approach?

The advantages that occur to me are these:

1. The mean distance of the nuts within any band might not be the mid-point of the band.  If, say, the mean distance is generally less than the mid-point, regression of N on MD will result in bias.  By contrast, regression of CN on D is unaffected by the distribution of distances within bands.
2. Both approaches depend upon banding, raising the risk that their results will depend on the particular banding structure chosen (see [Openshaw, The Modifiable Areal Unit Problem](http://qmrg.org.uk/files/2008/11/38-maup-openshaw.pdf)).  However, the cumulative approach seems less dependent: considering N and CN at MD = 17.5 and D = 20, for example, suppose 1 nut at distance 19.99 metres had been excluded by a marginally smaller band.  In that case, N would be reduced from 11 to 10, a difference of 9%, while CN would be reduced from 90 to 89, a difference of only 1.1%
3. Using CN avoids the complication of what to do with the zero values of N if a logged functional form appears appropriate.

An important disadvantage, as whuber has pointed out in his comment, is interdependency between the CN values.  Furthermore, heteroscedasticity in the N values will affect the CN values in a complex way. I am not aware of an estimation method that can handle these features - any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't mentioned a statistically important issue: the counts within separate bands are likely to be independent (and heteroscedastic) whereas the cumulative counts are strongly interdependent. Thus, any method of fitting the cumulative counts should be able to handle that dependence as well as the heteroscedasticity that is buried within it.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, yes on reflection interdependence of the cumulative values is an important issue.  I have edited the question to make it more balanced, including disadvantages as well as advantages.